# aggregate columns to new column based on another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frames is about attendance rate:

```
> df1
No.    grade1   grade2   grade3   grade4   grade5   grade6

A001        V        X        V        V        X        X
A002        X        V        V        V        X        V
A003        V        X        X        V        V        V
A004        X        X        V        V        X        V
A005        V        X        V        X        X        X
```

And I want re-label if any `V` showed in df1 based on df2,which is new group of grade.And about the `X` need to showed both of old columns then just label X.Because in real data maybe will have NA.I need to check student really skip class.

```
> df2
 group   new_group
grade1     grade20
grade2     grade20
grade3     grade21
grade4     grade21
grade5     grade22
grade6     grade22
```

That's mean if Student A001 have get `V` in grade1 or grade2,then Student A001 will get `V` in grade20, grade21 acorrding to grade3 and grade4 ,grade23 acorrding to grade5 and grade6.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
No.    grade20   grade21   grade22

A001        V        V        X 
A002        V        V        V 
A003        V        V        X 
A004        X        V        V 
A005        V        V        X
```

But I am not sure how to achieve what I want.Any help on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 |> 
  pivot_longer(-No., names_to = "group") |>
  left_join(df2, by = "group") |>
  group_by(No., new_group) |>
  summarize(value = ifelse("V" %in% value, "V", "X"), .groups = "drop") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = new_group, values_from = value)
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#   No.   grade20 grade21 grade22
#   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 A001  V       V       X      
# 2 A002  V       V       V      
# 3 A003  V       V       V      
# 4 A004  X       V       V      
# 5 A005  V       V       X
```

---

Using this sample data:

```
df1 = read.table(text = 'No.    grade1   grade2   grade3   grade4   grade5   grade6
A001        V        X        V        V        X        X
A002        X        V        V        V        X        V
A003        V        X        X        V        V        V
A004        X        X        V        V        X        V
A005        V        X        V        X        X        X', header = T)

df2 = read.table(text = 'group   new_group
grade1     grade20
grade2     grade20
grade3     grade21
grade4     grade21
grade5     grade22
grade6     grade22', header = T)
```

Comment: Hi, you are so awesome! Could I ask one more edited question about if  label "X" condition need to get all "X" in old group then label "X" to new group. I tried ```value = ifelse("V" %in% value, "V", ifelse("X" == value, "X", value)), .groups = "drop"``` ,ca't work.

Comment: If the only possibilities are "X" and "V", then you can negate my logic, `ifelse(!"V" %in% value, "X", "V")`. Or it might be more readable as `ifelse(all(value == "X"), "X", "V")`.

Comment: @ Gregor Thomas, I'm sorry for not clarify my question. In real date will have NA, I need to check the student real skip the class,so I need to make sure if all grade get X then label X in new,but if get X and NA, need to label NA.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, works like a charm!!! The real data go well.